# MATLAB student-t test from boxplot input

Tags: matlab, boxplot, significance

In Matlab I created some boxplots of data. Now, I would like to do a statistical analysis with a Student-T test, to see if the difference is significant. Some data is paired, others not, with difference in variance. I think a two tailed test should be used. Is their a function in matlab to calculate the Student-T test **from the boxplot**, so I do not need to calculated the imput values again?

regards,

Vincent

Comment: Are you referring to data in a figure or do you have the data in a matrix somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The boxplot figure itself only contains the information shown, i.e. the size of the box and the lines. It is theoretically possible to estimate the variance of the distribution from the inter-quartile-distance (you have to assume that your distribution follows a specific shape, though), but there is now way to guess the number of data points that went into the plot.

To get an accurate test, you're therefore much better off to re-calculate the input values.